# How come self deleted posts can become "Known-bad" Audits in the LQP queue?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I just stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12844868) Audit in the Low Quality Posts queue. I passed it because I noticed something fishy and clicked through to see that the actual answer had been deleted.

Turns out it was a complete answer although with a slightly underdisclosed link to a github (non commercial). I wouldn't have flagged this post as spam and I certainly wouldn't have recommended deletion on it if it wasn't an audit.

So my question is:

Why are self deleted answers candidates for "Known-Bad" Audits?

Screenshot for the Sub10k users:

[image]

Comment: This may make a poor isolated review audit, but is it the case that self-deleted posts selected in such a way are routinely bad as audits vs. other deleted posts?

Comment: It's not because it was self-deleted - it has a helpful spam flag on it...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was the mod that handled the spam flag as "helpful" - which is why the post is being used as an audit.

I can't remember why I marked that as helpful. Given the fact the answer is complete I would normally have declined the flag (or possibly disputed it). However, I didn't delete the post so I must have thought it had some value. I can only say that I must have misclicked.

Unfortunately as the system is automated it has to look at flags and how they were handled to determine whether to present the answer as an audit or not and when mistakes happen it can cause the system to throw out anomalies like this.

The only advice I can give is that if you get anything in the review queue where you really can't work out what's going on press "Skip" and go onto the next post.

Comment: Wouldn't that also mean that the post author lost 100 reputation from that post? If so, did you restore it?

Comment: @Magisch - no. Marking the flag as helpful doesn't give the 100 point penalty. That only happens if the post is deleted through the accumulation of enough spam (or rude/abusive) flags.

Comment: `That only happens if the post is deleted through the accumulation of enough spam (or rude/abusive) flags` [Six spam/rude/abusive flags, to be exact.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: @dorukayhan - it's less if a moderator flags it. Our flags are immediate and binding.